# VBS - Error opening connection using ADODB

Tags: vbscript, adodb

I'm having problems trying to connect in my oracle database using an ADODB object in VBScript, the code is working on a Win7 machine but not on WinXP, I tried to search for the error code, downloaded the sdk with the help file to look for something but I didn't found nothing useful.

Here is the code sample:

```
ConnectionString = "DSN=(Oracle in OraClient11g_home1);UID=username ;PWD=password ;DBQ=myDatabase"
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.Open ConnectionString 'the error occurs in this line
```

I don't know if the connection string must be different for winXP machines... I really don't know how to solve this, can someone help me?

The error trace information:

```
"Error #-2147024770: 
Error reported by: ADODB.Connection
Help File: 
Topic ID: 1240640"
```

Comment: Is the Oracle driver installed on the XP machine?

Comment: C:\Users\>net helpmsg 126 The specified module could not be found. The line above the error line hasn't worked. XP has ado 2.7 while Vista has 6.

Comment: @aphoria yes the driver is installed and I can connect on the database using sqlplus, pl/sql developer, etc..

Comment: Nonetheless it can't find a dll. Use windbg or ntsd (already installed in non home versions) to see which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-2147024770 = FFFFFFFF8007007E
```

To Decode 0x8007nnnn Errors

HResults with facility code 7 means the HResult contains a Windows' error code. You have to look up the Windows' error code not the HResult.

To decode 0x8007007e. The 0x means it's a hexadecimal number, the 8 means error, the first 7 means it a windows error, and the rest of the number, 7e, is the actual Windows error.

To look up the error we need it in decimal format. Start Calculator (Start - All Programs - Accessories - Calculator) and choose View menu - Scientific, then View menu - Hex. Enter 7e. Then View menu -  Decimal. It will say 126.

Start a Command Prompt (Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt) and type

```
net helpmsg 126
```

and it will say

```
The specified module could not be found.
```

or look it up in winerror.h

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
// The specified module could not be found.
//
#define ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND              126L
```

To see what is happening start your program in ntsd.

Start a command prompt.

Type

```
md c:\symbols
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*C:\tmp*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\symbols
```

then (changing it to your program from notepad)

```
ntsd -g -o c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

so something

```
ntsd -g -o wscript "c:\folder\script.vbs"
```

and wait for the error.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but I got this message when I try to run my script: `Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***`